# How to check new urls against csv of old urls in python to prevent duplicates?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I first grab all article urls from an RSS feed and check for duplicates within that list. I then want to check those unique article urls against a csv file of old article urls to avoid duplicates with the csv list. I only want to print out the new urls that didn't match with the old urls in the csv.

I'm having trouble with the latter part, any help is appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


feed_urls = ["https://www.example.com/rss"]

with open("Old_Articles.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as r:
    old_articles = csv.reader(r, delimiter=",")

    for url in feed_urls:
        response = requests.get(url)
        html_source = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "xml")
        new_articles = set()

        for link in soup.findAll("atom:link"):
            new_articles.add(link.get("href"))

        for link in new_articles:
            if link not in old_articles:
                print("Not Matched")
            else:
                print("Matched")
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out what's getting added to 'new_articles', and what's contained in 'old_articles'?  Your method for searching seems fine, so I think your problem is likely that you're not getting what you expected saved to those variables.

Comment: Consider that each item of `old_articles` could have some unwanted formatting artifacts (ie. leading or trailing spaces) as a result of storage in CSV

Comment: seems like you only want the urls which are *not* in `old_articles`. Try: `for url in feed_urls: if url not in list(old_articles)` ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, so when I print the articles from the rss versus the csv, I assume they don't match because of the formatting? https://www.example.com/same_article
['https://www.example.com/same_article']